# Bash - Looping through files in a directory

Tags: bash, loops

I know there are lots of questions like that but for the love of all the gods I can't get it to work or I am missing something completely obvious, in that case please forgive..

Simple directory, and I want to call the name of the file and mime type of each:

```
for i in "attachments/*"
do
     echo $i $(file --mime-type -b $i)
done
```

Why does my output look like:

```
attachments/query.sql attachments/script.sh text/plain text/x-shellscript
```

when I expect:

```
attachments/query.sql text/plain attachments/script.sh text/x-shellscript
```

Comment: Gods will smile if you do `for i in "attachments/"*` and move the `*` outside the quotes so that it actually expands as a wildcard `:)`

Comment: Oh for gods' sakes.. I am a numpty... Thank you gents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need quotes around `/tmp/attach/*`.

```
for i in /tmp/attach/*
do
     echo "$i : $(file --mime-type -b $i)"
done
```

When you use quotes, then you are passing `/tmp/attach/*` to `file` command, not just one by one filenames.

Comment: If you don't set `shopt -s nullglob`, bash's for loop isn't smart enough to not try to execute the body with just the pattern.  Which `file` will through and error about.  I set it prior to a for loop, and then unset it after the body.

Comment: But you might need quotes around `$i` inside the command substitution. Also check for `[ -e "$i" ] || continue`